# Why are there two н's in «c мороженной формой» and not just one?

Tags: орфография

**Из-под сена виднелись: самовар, кадка с мороженной формой и ещё кой-какие привлекательные узелки и коробочки.**

Why is there a double -нн- in the word „мороженной“? And, more importantly, *what rule is at work here*? (among the dozens of rules pertaining to -н- over -нн-.)

No prefix, no -ованн-/-еванн- suffix, and apparently no dependent words (жареная картошка, жаренная в масле картошка).

Comment: Авторская орфография? Забыли включить в список исключений наряду со "священный" и "жеманный"? Чтобы отличать от существительного "мороженое"?

Comment: Вот тут процитировали с одной Н: https://studfile.net/preview/9299857/page:10/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Why is there double -нн- in the word „мороженной“?

In this case, the word *мороженной* does not mean "frozen" (either as an adjective or as a participle). It's an adjective derived from the noun *мороженое* (which is a substantivized participle in its own right), and means "related to ice cream".

In most languages of the world, this kind of secondary derivation tends to negate the custom patterns and irregularities applicable to the original word.

In English, when you're talking about the family of Peter and Stacey Child, you call them "the Childs", not "*the Children". When a baseball player hits a "fly ball", they say "he flied" (not "*flew"). The Canadian ice hockey team is "Toronto Maple Leafs", not "*Leaves", and so on.

In Russian, such secondary derivations are less common, but still happen. The region around the city of Kurgan is called *Курганская область*, not **Курганная*, even though the etymology of the city name is known and quite transparent.   Personal names like *Любовь/Любови, Заяц/Заяца, Журавель/Журавеля* etc. also accept a more regular declension pattern than their etymons with fleeting vowels (*thx @SergeySlepov*).

The same thing happens with the word *морожен(н)ая* here; the secondary derivation negates the previous rules.

---

> And, more importantly, what rule applies?

There is no "rule" because, apparently, no one has ever bothered to codify this pattern (adjective derived from a substantivized past passive participle with *-н-*).

The only other example of such an adjective I could think of is *придан(н)ое* ("related to dowry"), and it looks like the usage with *-н-* is prevalent:

> - Отказавшись лично от этой операции, Менандр Семенович предоставил ведение ее жене тем охотнее, что последняя, как было всем известно, имела свой приданый капитал и свою приданую деревню. *[М. Е. Салтыков-Щедрин. Господа ташкентцы. Картины нравов (1869-1872)]*
> - Трудиться она не умела и никогда не пускалась ни в какие рассуждения о труде, а с младенческою беспечностью проживала свои приданые деньжонки, сбереженные для нее мужем. *[Н. С. Лесков. Некуда (1864)]*

, although *-нн-* occurs as well:

> - Бывало, когда муж разобидит ее своим барством и бездушием и уедет в клуб спускать ее прида́нные деньги, она сядет к роялю и, часто против воли, заиграет этот ноктюрн. *[П. Д. Боборыкин. Василий Теркин (1892)]*

I couldn't find any other use of the adjective *морожен(н)ое* in this derived sense other than in this quote from Tolstoy.

Secondarily derived adjectives are being used now and then in Russian, (*беременное платье, глухонемая школа* etc.), but they're not formed from past passive participles, so this ambiguity doesn't arise with them.

This kind of word formation isn't universally accepted or liked, so if I were to write something like this, I'd use an analytic construct: *форма для мороженого, платье для беременных, школа для глухонемых* etc.

If you still want to use these forms in your writing, you're on your own. Leo Tolstoy's example is as good as any, but it's the only one I could find, so there just isn't enough material to speak of any patterns.

Comment: What an excellent answer. I've often wondered about this myself and never bothered to ask. As a matter of fact, just last week I came across an article about popular American desserts and they mentioned жареное мороженое! A double whammy!)))

Comment: It's funny you mentioned the Childs. In English, we have a word, *manchild*, which is basically a little boy in a man's body. Although most dictionaries prescribe the plural *man/men-children*, most people actually say *manchilds*. I thought it was a purely American thing, then I saw this article: https://www.mumsnet.com/talk/am_i_being_unreasonable/1994428-to-beg-women-with-lazy-sexist-arsehole-DHs-not-to-have-more-DCs-with-them (last sentence in first paragraph) 

Comment: @CocoPop: English examples are from one of John Mcwhorter's books (can't remember which and I'm not next to them at the moment)

Comment: They're great examples. I was just adding one more) If you're reacting to the fact that I said "it's funny you mentioned", that just means "what a coincidence" ;)

Comment: The Russian equivalent of the Childs would be the surnames such as За́яц – За́яца, Жураве́ль – Жураве́ля, Реме́нь – Реме́ня, etc.

Answer (score -1):

Незаконченный фрагмент, читаем дальше:

Из-под сена виднелись: самовар, кадка **с мороженной** формой и еще кой-какие привлекательные узелки и коробочки. Нельзя было ошибиться: это был чай на чистом воздухе, **мороженое** и фрукты.

Самовар -> чай / мороженная форма -> мороженое / привлекательные узелки и коробочки -> фрукты.

So, this text like a reverse puzzle.

Самовар is for tea, "freezish(?)" form is **for** ice cream, pretty boxes is for fruits (fruits was very lacking).

Форма не мороженое или мороженая(freezed), а **для** поделки мороженого ~ the form for ice cream making, an ice cream mold/dish.

For ice cream making - мороженная, мороженный - but rarely, because more useful is "форма **для** мороженого".

Мороже**нн**ый - прилагательное производное от существительного мороже**н**ое, относящийся к мороженому, но не являющийся мороженым.

Правило звучит как: две буквы НН пишутся в прилагательных, образованных от существительных

1. **с основой на Н** (КАРТИН+Ный, ОСЕН+Ний)
2. при помощи суффикса – онн – (революционный, лекционный)
3. при помощи суффикса – енн – (соломенный). Исключение: ветреный (но безветренный)

То есть "мороженная форма" попадает как под "1" **Морожен**ое <- **морожен+н**+ая форма, по аналогии с **картин**а <- карти**нн**ая галерея.

Другой возможный случай образования с помощью удвоения Н+Н, это картон -> картонный - состоящий из картона (consisted/composited of) - картон+н+ая коробка.

Это не связано напрямую с суффиксом ЕНН или ОНН или другими, вроде СК. СК - это суффикс значащий - **чей?**/ **к чему относящийся?** а не про случай ЕН - **какой?**

Курган - город или дословно "холм/насыпь", курганский - относящийся к кургану непосредственно, но им не являющийся - кроме кургана то есть. Курганский вид, курганский цветок, Курганская область - то что вне кургана. Курганная - возможный вариант названия топонимов внутри города Курган или происходящая от курган-холм, например - Курганная улица, например, то есть это уже улица, но и курган одновременно, а Курганская область - это то, что не Курган-город, не включающая его в свои пределы.

Случай же удвоение Н+Н больше похож на: plan — planning, stop - stopping и тп. То есть данное удвоение может происходить, когда согласная входит в часть "основы слова". Основа слова - это часть слова несущая семантическое значения класса похожих слов, в ней часто не выделяют суффикс, хотя этимологические корень слова может быть короче основы. Мороженое - от мороз/морож, но основа будет "морожен".

PS.: "*freezish*" -  i tryed to make an adjective form.

Comment: Please no public display of affection in the comments section. Find a private room in the chat. Thank you.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/148611/discussion-on-answer-by--why-are-there-two-s-in-c--); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.